# UserProfileApplicationProxy Proxy is null

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

I've a server running SP 2016, the web application can't browsed and show

> The page can't be displayed

I checked the log, I'm getting this error

> The Execute method of job definition
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Directory.SharePoint.Provider.UnifiedGroupContentDbOperationsJob
>   (ID 9778ac88-17fa-45e8-85d2-70f15bc737d5) threw an exception. More
>   information is included below.
>
> UserProfileApplicationProxy Proxy is null.
>   (Correlation=5de2f29d-3008-f067-48e5-5cd569e242a8)

PS:the user profile sync service is not configured ,

Any suggestions on solving this puzzle?